# Drag and drop nested list with stimulus and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulus-reflex

I need to do a draggable (drag and drop) nested list with use of stimulus + RoR.

Expected behaviour: When user drops an item (item A) inside another one (Item B) - Item B should became parent item for Item A. Any tips how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with sortable js.

There is also a ready-made Stimulus controller in Stimulus Components that you could get inspiration from.

https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable

https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-sortable

https://github.com/stimulus-components/stimulus-sortable/